# VBA EXCEL HTML - Scraping data from website within a frame, from a span

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

**Background**

I'm about 10 weeks into being self taught VBA. The below code I've only just picked up in the last week as it relates to IE/HTML.. Now I've gone so far with automating this process with the clicking of buttons and scraping of data. There is just one thing left that I just can not problem solve for the life of me. And I know it's complicated but I'm not skilled enough to resolve..

My code is below:

```
Sub TPMRebatePayment()


    Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim frame As HTMLFrameElement
    Dim imgShowAdvSearch As HTMLImg
    Dim imgGoTo As HTMLImg
    Dim imgEditDet As HTMLImg
    Dim wkbSourceWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceShtClm As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    'Dim LastRow_Clm As Long    'Do I need to DIM this??
    'Dim LastRow_TPM As Long    'Do I need to DIM this??
    Dim cRow1 As Long
    Dim cRow2 As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim jRow As Long
    Dim dblStartTime As Double         'time elapsed counter
    Dim strMinutesElapsed As String

    dblStartTime = Timer

    Set wkbSourceWB = ThisWorkbook     'Set workbook
    Set SourceShtClm = wkbSourceWB.Sheets("Claim Summary")
    Set SourceShtTPM = wkbSourceWB.Sheets("TPM Payment")

    response = MsgBox("Have you open IE and logged onto CRM?", vbYesNo, "Internet Explorer Question")
    If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    'Cleares data from "TPM Payment" tab
    SourceShtTPM.Rows("4:" & Rows.Count).Delete          'deletes data
    SourceShtTPM.Range("A3:B3, D3:E3, J3").ClearContents            'clears data

    'Copies Accruals from "Promo Claims" tab to "TPM Payment" tab
    LastRow_Clm = SourceShtClm.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For cRow1 = 4 To LastRow_Clm
        If SourceShtClm.Range("P" & cRow1) = "" Then
            LastRow_TPM = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            SourceShtClm.Range("N" & cRow1).Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & LastRow_TPM + 1)
            SourceShtClm.Range("O" & cRow1).Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("B" & LastRow_TPM + 1)
        End If
    Next cRow1

    For cRow2 = 4 To LastRow_Clm
        If SourceShtClm.Range("S" & cRow2) = "" Then
            LastRow_TPM = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Recalc last row as data has been entered
            SourceShtClm.Range("Q" & cRow2).Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & LastRow_TPM + 1)
            SourceShtClm.Range("R" & cRow2).Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("B" & LastRow_TPM + 1)
        End If
    Next cRow2

    'Copies formulas in TPM tab
    LastRow_TPM = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Recalc last row as data has been entered
    SourceShtTPM.Range("C3").Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("C" & LastRow_TPM)
    SourceShtTPM.Range("F3:I3").Copy SourceShtTPM.Range("F4:I" & LastRow_TPM)

    'Opens IE
    IE.navigate "http://crmprdas02.aunz.lncorp.net:8011/sap(bD1lbiZjPTEwMCZkPW1pbg==)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_bsp_frame/entrypoint.do?appl=crmd_stlmt_rb&version=0&blview=znfl_stl&crm_bsp_restore=false"
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    'Loops thru entering payments
    LastRow = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Recalc last row as data has been entered

    For iRow = 3 To LastRow

        If SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & iRow) <> "" Then

            Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
            Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("crmA")(0)
            Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__simpleSearch__as_button").Click   'Click Search Button
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__advancedSearch_advancedSearch_REBATE_NO").Value = SourceShtTPM.Range("A" & iRow).Value    'Enter Accrual into Rebate No. Field
            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SREQ1_SR__advancedSearch__sm_go").Click
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            HTMLdoc.getElementById("SRES2_BUT_GOTO").Click      'Click Go To Button
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
            HTMLdoc.getElementById("EDIT_DETAILS").Click        'Then Details to enter the payment page
            While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

            AccBal = HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZACCRUED_SC").Value       'Scrapes accrual balance
            If Right(AccBal, 1) = "-" Then                                                          'Converts to number
                SourceShtTPM.Range("E" & iRow).Value = "-" & Left(AccBal, Len(AccBal) - 1)
                Else: SourceShtTPM.Range("E" & iRow).Value = "-" & AccBal
            End If

            If SourceShtTPM.Range("H" & iRow).Value > 0 Then       'Confirms if enough money to pay

                HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZAMOUNT").Value = Round(SourceShtTPM.Range("H" & iRow).Value, 2)   'Enters "Amount to be Paid"
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_DETL31_MULT3_DETL31ES_ZZCLAIMNO_SC").Value = SourceShtTPM.Range("A2").Value       'Enters claim no.
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_BUT_ZST_CPY_RT").Click     'Click button to distribute
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("ZCR_COPY_TO_SKU_RATE").Click            'distributes to sku
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_BUT_ZSTL_COPY").Click      'Click button to distribute
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("ZCR_COPY_TO_SKU_AMNT").Click            'distributes to sku
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_ZSTL_PART_SETTLE").Click   'Clicks Pay Claim
                While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
                'The line below will save the rebate payment.
                'DO NOT REMOVE ' UNLESS CODE IS 100%
                'HTMLdoc.getElementById("MULT3_MEDL32_ZCR_STLMT_SAVE").Click    'Clicks Save
                'While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend


                'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP!!!


                SourceShtTPM.Range("J" & iRow) = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("urTxtStd").innerText     'Gets text


                'END OF HELP


                'Col "Y" = entered commentary
                SourceShtTPM.Range("D" & iRow).Value = "Claim Paid"

            Else

                'Col "Y" = payment amount to enter
                SourceShtTPM.Range("D" & iRow).Value = "Not Paid"

            End If

        IE.navigate "http://crmprdas02.aunz.lncorp.net:8011/sap(bD1lbiZjPTEwMCZkPW1pbg==)/bc/bsp/sap/crm_bsp_frame/entrypoint.do?appl=crmd_stlmt_rb&version=0&blview=znfl_stl&crm_bsp_restore=false"
        While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing

        End If

    Next iRow

    IE.Quit

    strMinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - dblStartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")        'stops timer - Determine how many seconds code took to run

    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & strMinutesElapsed, vbInformation        'Msg box for elapsed time & Claims consldaited

End Sub
```

**Problem**

Below are 2 pics of the 'Inspect Elements' of the web I trying to scrape info from. I want the text "Promotion start date has not yet been reached."

I would love some help please. And if possible, I'd like an explanation so I can understand the code being provided. The more I learn, the more I can help others.

[image: Pic 1/2]

[image: Pic 2/2]

Comment: Please include HTML between code tags using the snippet tool via [edit]. We cannot test easily from an image nor robustly.

Comment: Can't you just parse the data by using instr function to find the span class name. As far as I can see the span class is unique thus instr should give you a position. Use mid and this position and you should get the html of the class and the promotion text. Then just parse it from there. Most likely the html tag is a fixed number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

In your pastebin it is simply accessible by id

```
Debug.Print ie.document.getElementById("APLG0_lnk").innerText
```

---

For elements with parent frame and form tags: You have to account for the `frame` in your selection path. The `form` possibly.

To account for the frame only, and use the id of the target element, you would use syntax such as:

```
 Debug.Print Ie.document.getElementsByName("crmA")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("APLG0_lnk").innerText
```

Similarly, syntax such as:

```
Debug.Print Ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("APLG0_1nk").innerText
```

In the less likely event of needing to account for `form`, something like:

```
Debug.Print Ie.document.getElementsByName("crmA")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("form #APLG0_lnk").innerText
```

Comment: I tried all 3 and nothing printed.. There is only 1 frame with the name "crmA"

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Oh auto spell thingy in Word has changed the casing of it. One sec. I have edited to correctly be crmA.

Comment: If doesn't work please can you [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)  entire html document from <HTML> to  </HTML>

Comment: Also, no errors when I ran the code above. Still ok, just no debug.print.. (yes I have the immediate window open)

Comment: updated answer. From your supplied HTML it is simply  ie.document.getElementById("APLG0_lnk").innerText. Do you have an On Error Resume Next in your code by chance?

Comment: No 'on error resume next'... Tried the updated code and it doesnt work..  still no debug print.. I will play around and research more to see if I can get this working, thanks for looking

Comment: Does it matter that the start of my loop set the HTMLDoc?

Comment: I ran it fine using the HTML you supplied. You are really getting no error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182211/discussion-between-qharr-and-alowflyingpig).